# Community detection in R thanks to the igraph package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph, detection

I have a data.frame with the correlations between OTUs and genes. These correlations will allow me to construct genomes. This data.frame has 1105854 rows.

```
      var1                var2  corr
1  OTU3978 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.846
2  OTU4011 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.855
3  OTU4929 UniRef90_A0A010P3Z8 0.829
4  OTU4317 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.850
5  OTU4816 UniRef90_A0A011P550 0.807
6  OTU3902 UniRef90_A0A011QPQ2 0.836
7  OTU3339 UniRef90_A0A011RKI6 0.835
8  OTU1359 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.801
9  OTU2085 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.843
10 OTU3542 UniRef90_A0A011RLA7 0.866
11 OTU0473 UniRef90_A0A011TDE1 0.807
```

I use the igraph library to build a graph object.

`g<-graph.data.frame(df)`

Then, I want to extract components of this graph in order to construct genomes : I mean, one component will correspond to one genome.

I tried this command : `genomes<-split(names(V(g)),components(g)$membership)`

It gives me back several components, for example :

```
> genomes[[4]]
[1] "OTU2417"             "UniRef90_A0A076H0Q4" "UniRef90_A0A2E8T3F8"
[4] "UniRef90_G5ZY43"
```

I check the OTU and the different genes of each component thanks to my OTUs table and thanks to the EMBL-EBI database for the genes. I can determine if each reconstructed genome is meaningful.

I also checked the documentation, and I found many other community detection methods : edge-betweenness, louvain, multi-level ... I would like to know what is the main difference between the command line I used ( which gives me back pretty meaningful components) and these algorithms (which also give me components) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the clusters you wish to find to be weakly disconnected from eachother in your graph, using component search will work. If you expect there to be connections between clusters, these will get grouped together in the completeness search.

Louvain and edge-betweeness don't have this restriction, they try to find an optimal partition/community assignment/clustering by maximizing an objective, modularity and betweeness respectively. The modularity approach suffers from a resolution limit: very small but distinct communities will never be recognized in a large enough graph. Keep this in mind if you expect to find many smaller clusters.